# ListView Custom ArrayAdapter - Changes textbutton from Button OnClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter, custom-adapter

I want to change textbutton on button onclicklistener but for every 5 row textbutton display same result. I just want change text button for 1 button clicked

xml layout childview

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_seatmap"
    style="@style/buttonSeatMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_kereta_tiba"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_info_seat"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="@string/btn_seatmap" />
```

xml layout listview

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_kereta"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_pilih_jadwal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title_jadwal_kai"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

and here code from custom adapter

```
@Override
public View getView(final int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    View view = arg1;
    ListHolder listHolder = null;

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, arg2, false);

        listHolder = new ListHolder();
        listHolder.layout = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.layout_jadwal_kai);
        listHolder.txtNama = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_nama_kereta);
        listHolder.txtBerangkat = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_kereta_brkt);
        listHolder.txtHarga = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_harga_kereta);
        listHolder.txtTiba = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_kereta_tiba);
        listHolder.txtClass = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_kelas_kereta);
        listHolder.txtSeat = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_info_seat);
        listHolder.btnSeatMap = (Button) view
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_seatmap);
        CheckSeatOnProgress = false;
        view.setTag(listHolder);
    } else {
        listHolder = (ListHolder) view.getTag();
    }
        listHolder.btnSeatMap.setTag(listHolder);
        listHolder.btnSeatMap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ListHolder holder = (ListHolder) v.getTag();
                holder.btnSeatMap.setText("TEST");

                // listHolder.btnSeatMap.setText("TEST");
            });
```

adapter code

```
public void refreshListJadwal() {
    adapter = new AdapterListKereta(getActivity(),
            R.layout.custom_list_jadwalkai, setGetJadwals, dataJadwalKereta);
    listKereta.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

"TEST" display for every 5 row.
please help. thank you

Comment: Post adapter code

Comment: @Raghavendra I have updated my question

Comment: In the onclick can u try like this? ((Button)v).setText("TEST"); ?

Comment: @Raghavendra still same result, textbutton display same result every 5 row

Comment: Can you try Mangal's answer?

Comment: It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270472/android-listview-change-item-button-text-after-clicking

Comment: @Raghavendra still same, 5 row display TEST

Comment: anyone can help ?

Comment: try this https://pmahsky8389.wordpress.com/2015/03/12/android-list-view-recycling-issue/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around, Not an optimal solution though :D try this,

```
private HashMap<Integer, String> selected = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

@Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View arg1, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = arg1;
        ListHolder listHolder = null;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            listHolder = new ListHolder();
            listHolder.nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listitem1);
            listHolder.btnSeatMap = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.listbtn1);
            view.setTag(listHolder);
        } else {
            listHolder = (ListHolder) view.getTag();

        }

        if(selected != null && !selected.isEmpty() && selected.get(position) != null )
            listHolder.btnSeatMap.setText("TEST");
        else {
            listHolder.btnSeatMap.setText("");
        }

        listHolder.btnSeatMap.setTag(position);
        listHolder.nameTextView.setText(itemsArrayList[position]);
        listHolder.btnSeatMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int which = -1;
                Object obj = v.getTag();
                if (obj instanceof Integer)
                {
                    which = (Integer) obj;
                }
                Log.e("POSISITON", which+"");
                selected.put(which, "TEST");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }});

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Whatever it is, it solves my problem. thank you @Raghavendra

Comment: Glad! that helped.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change text of button after click then you can use ArrayList.

1)set position as tag to button

2)When button clicked, then find position form tag

3)Get respective text from created ArrayList by position and set this text to clicked view.

Comment: listHolder.btnSeatMap.setTag(arg0);
int posButton = (Integer) v.getTag();
btnCheck.setText(data.get(posButton).getnmKereta());

still same result, textbutton display same text for every 5 row